# Outliers over multiple time series

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, outliers, sentiment-analysis

I got roughly 400 time-series measurements which are concerned with the sentiment of chat messages from different videos. I want to detect if there are videos which have a higher or lower sentiment than most of the other streams.
I struggle to find a good way to detect this, due to the following properties:

- different length of measurements. The duration of the measurement ranges from 30min to 10h
- Lots of neutral sentiments. The sentiment values range from -1 to +1, but a large majority of the sentiment values are located at 0. Therefore, statistics like the mean or median do not work properly because the large number of 0 values prevents a useful result
- Unpredictability of the data. I already looked through several posts / articles, and found that some of them refer to a trend analysis / decomposition of the time series. Unfortunately, the data does not follow a predictable pattern at all, nor can it be divided in seasonal sections.

Here is an example of one such time-series:
[image: sentiment time-series]

As a "cheap alternative" I tried to divided the time-series's into sections, calculated the median there over all time-series measurements, and compared the median values with the sectional-median from an individual measurement, but found that measurements with less data-points show a larger difference, because here less 0-values can influence the median.

Is there by any chance a method to do this in a scientific manner? I feel like this should be a relatively common problem, but as stated before, I could not find some reference or literature to solve this.

Any help is appreciated!